# setMinDate() for DatePicker

Tags: android, datepicker

I saw this question on stack overflow in several places, but the given answers does not work for me, so here I am :).

I need to set a date picker's minimum date dynamically to the current date. My minimum API is 12.

I tried this:

```
Calendar minCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
minCalendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, minCalendar.MILLISECOND - 1000);

DatePicker endDatePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker2);
endDatePicker.setMinDate(minCalendar.getTimeInMillis());
```

I don't get any errors, only the date picker is not set to today. It is set to 'October 1964'....

Please help me...

EDITED

I also tried this, but the same effect:

```
endDatePicker.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [my similar question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16664562/setting-mindate-on-datepicker-moves-calendarview-to-1964/16671925#16671925):

```
// Calendar view is a cascade of bugs.
// Work around that by explicitly disabling it.
datePicker.setCalendarViewShown(false);
```

If a working calendar view with the date picker is a priority for you, I'd consider forking the platform code and fixing the bugs there.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Time now = new Time();
now.setToNow();

DatePicker endDatePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker2);
endDatePicker.setMinDate(now.toMillis(false));
```