# Setting the time for both DatePicker fields in a DatePickerDialog

Tags: android, user-interface, datepicker, android-calendar, datepickerdialog

I am trying to create a DatePickerDialog when a certain TextView is clicked, and then set the date picked to be that TextView. I have gotten this to work, but when the DatePickerDialog is shown, the dates for left DatePicker are correctly set to the current date, while the calendar on the right is set to November 2100. How can I access the field of calendar and set its date?

Here is a link to an image of what I am talking about, but is not from my application exactly.
http://i1023.photobucket.com/albums/af358/shaikhhamadali/typesofdialog_4_zps078711ac.png

So, I am talking about the calendar on the right that does not start on the current date. I would like to know how to access it? If I'm not mistaken, this calendar will only show on tablets, so is there a "safe" way to do this where running it on a phone would not cause any problems?

Here is the code from my DatePickerFragment innerclass onCreateDialog method

```
 @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
            datePickerDialog.setTitle("Enter date");
            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() / 86400000L * 86400000L);


            return datePickerDialog;
        }
```

Thank you for any help!

UPDATE:

Update: I have tried adding accessing the CalendarView through both, but the CalendarView still starts up at Nov 2100

```
  datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().getCalendarView().setDate(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() / 86400000L *86400000L);

    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().getCalendarView().setMinDate(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() / 86400000L  86400000L);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

[This long answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16671925/1797533) (to a question about practically the same bug) suggests a workaround for this issue.

Part of it quoted here:

> `formatDateRange()` does not work past 2038.
>
> ## Workaround #1

```
class DatePickerDialog1964 extends DatePickerDialog {
    DatePickerDialog1964(Context c) {
        super(c, null, 2013, 4, 21);

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Date min = new Date(2013-1900, 4, 21);

        DatePicker p = getDatePicker();
        CalendarView cv = p.getCalendarView(); // should check for null
        long cur = cv.getDate();
        int d = cv.getFirstDayOfWeek();
        p.setMinDate(min.getTime());
        cv.setDate(cur + 1000L*60*60*24*40);
        cv.setFirstDayOfWeek((d + 1) % 7);
        cv.setDate(cur);
        cv.setFirstDayOfWeek(d);
    }
}
```

> ## Workaround #2 I actually used

```
// Calendar view is a cascade of bugs.
// Work around that by explicitly disabling it.
datePicker.setCalendarViewShown(false);
```

### My Deduction

By elimination, we can deduce that the line `datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() / 86400000L * 86400000L);` is causing the November 2100 error.

`(UNIX time / 86400000L) * 86400000L` --I guess it's supposed to take advantage of rounding to produce a 'full' day. Beware of it rounding to the same day if the current time is after noon, the previous day if before. It isn't chopping after the floating point.

About the updated part:
Even calling `setMinDate` then `setDate`  isn't really solving anything -- The problem that caused the Nov 2100 error will persist, because the updated line's effect is executed by the original code.

Then I looked around, and I found the above linked answer.
I guess CalendarView is stuffed with bugs.

*There appears to be another NumberPicker bug where the previous month and date and shown sometimes, even if not accessible. They disappear when we try to access them.*

*P.S: I know this is late, but since the OP didn't provide any solution, an analysis might be helpful to somebody.*